# How can i store a Aces High Pin on the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ether

I have a few Aces High Pin's laying around and wanted to know how i can store them on the Eth blockchain.

Comment: Unfortunately the type of people you will commonly find on StackExchange have no sense of humor. When exposed to humor they may feel nausea, or at worst suffer a heart attack. Therefore; to protect the health of the StackExchange community I have to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Storing collectibles or titles to physical objects on the Ethereum blockchain is usually accomplished by writing a smart contract that implements the ERC721 interface.

You can find its specification here: http://erc721.org/

And you can use OpenZeppelin's implementation as a template to get started: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol

However, if your collectibles are fungible and all identical, you may want to stick with the simpler ERC20 interface.

Good luck with your Aces High Pins, which arguably are the best collectibles ever created by mankind. Maybe one lucky day we will discover a distant planet or asteroid with plenty of them for your collecting pleasure :)

Merry Christmas and a happy new year!